# Set up an email server on a VPS behind an Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, email-server, reverse-proxy, vps

To start off, I am technically a hobbyist but I feel the topic of the question is more suited to here than say Superuser. If I'm wrong, I'm sure you'll all tell me.

I have an Ubuntu VPS that currently hosts a website as well as some personal node.js projects (some of these are in docker containers, others aren't), all sitting behind an Nginx reverse proxy. I need to set up an email server on this VPS (only one domain for now, but potential for easy expansion is preferable) and have no experience of doing this. I need to have SMTP and IMAP access for email clients, web interface isn't strictly required but it's always good as a backup.

I was looking at [poste.io](https://poste.io/) as a potential solution since it 1) runs in a docker container and 2) actually has my exact scenario on their [network schemes page](https://poste.io/doc/network-schemes) (scheme 2) although it doesn't appear they have any documentation of how to actually set it up this way.

I'd like to know:

1. Am I missing a glaringly obvious solution
2. Is there a better solution than Poste.io that's easy(er?) to set up
3. What would I need to add to my Nginx config (if not already obvious in documentation)
4. What changes would I need to make to ubuntu (again, if not already obvious in documentation)

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, get another VPS. Mail is already one of the most complex things we will ever do in this profession. Adding to the complexity by trying to colocate it with a web server, with _no experience_, seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael is saying, you may want to consider using a separate VPS to avoid potential bad setup on your existing system. At the same time, if the existing VPS is not your livelihood, then it's certainly less of an issue.

email is really difficult to setup properly no matter what when you install your own server. On my end, I've been using `postfix` along with `postgrey`. Note that by default `postfix` is installed with `courier` which doesn't support TLS 1.2+ properly. You'll want to use `dovecot` instead, if you use that solution.

```
sudo apt-get install postfix postgrey
```

The main thing to setup is the `/etc/postfix/main.cf`. One of the main parameter to update is the following:

```
mydestination = mail.example.com, mail.example2.com, mail.example3.com
```

and as you can see, you can have as many domains as you want without much work. You'll want to test, you may also want to include the plain domain name (`example.com`, `example2.com`, etc.) so emails can be sent to your domain as in `john@example.com`.

As for proxying through Nginx, you can read [this Nginx page](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/mail-proxy/mail-proxy/). On my end I never tried to proxy emails. I'm not too sure what would be the point if you have exactly one VPS. Proxies are useful for two main reasons:

1. as a load balancer, you have one point of access and many VPS and the proxy distributes traffic in various ways -- sending the data to a VPS which is not too busy
2. as a security measure by blocking some invalid (unwanted) traffic

I'm not so sure that Nginx can do much of that for emails for you, but I may be wrong.

Note: having a website in a docker is very similar to having a separate VPS so often you need a proxy for those, especially if you have many. On my end I run many websites on one VPS without proxy. Apache2 can handle any number of websites with SSL without the need for the extra traffic routing and it can still do some of (2) by blocking some requests (see the mod_security extension).